# Como copiar um valor dentro de um span

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso copiar um valor de dentro de um `span` que é gerado por um slider, ele sempre que mexe no slider ele é alterado. Tem como eu colocar ele dentro de um valor de um um input?

Tentei isso e não deu certo:

```
<h4>Valor do consórcio: <span class="slider-value quote-form-element valor-carro1" data-name="Valor | Automóvel" name="Valor" data-slider-id="consorcio-auto">R$ <span id="THAT_VALUE"></span></span>
                            </h4>
<div class="slider" data-slider-min="20000" data-slider-max="100000" data-slider-start="23192" data-slider-step="1000" data-slider-id="consorcio-auto"></div>

<h4>Seus dados:</h4>
<input type="hidden" id="THAT_FIELD" name="THAT_FIELD" value="" />
<h4>Seus dados:</h4>
<input type="hidden" id="valorcarro" name="valorcarro" value=""  />
```

Script:

```
$(function(){
var valorcarro = $('#THAT_VALUE').html();
$('#THAT_FIELD').val(valorcarro);
});
```

O problema é que com esse script o valor no input fica em branco, pois o texto do span só é gerado depois, e o usuário ainda consegue mudar ele.

Exemplo nessa [página](http://consorciomenegalli.com.br/teste.html) no botão "Simulação" no menu.

Comment: Tu tem que fazer isso toda vez que o usuário alterar o slider, dá uma olhada no evento change desse plugin que você tá usando. O que pode te ajudar, mas é gambiarra é colocar essa sua função dentro de um $(document).change(function() { //function here });

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o seguinte para obter o valor do slider:

```
<!-- adicionei um id para simplificar o exemplo -->
<div class="slider" id="slider" ...... >


$('#THAT_FIELD').val($('#slider').slider('option', 'value'));
```